# How to validate the dynamically created textboxes in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have created textboxes dynamically when button is clicked.But even if the text box is empty it is saving the text boxes.But i have number of text boxes which are created dynamically.how to identify the particular empty text box and validate it.I am trying the validation when save button is clicked.Can anyone help me to solve this.

```
//onclick creating textboxes

$scope.expndtxt=function(){


        $scope.textboxes.push("");

    };

//view 

    <li ng-repeat="textbox in textboxes track by $index">
                Label For Inputfield:
                    <input type="text" id="in_{{$index}}" data-ng-model="$parent.textboxes[$index]"/><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="deletetxtbox($index)">-</button>
            </li>
```

Comment: Please add current your code.

Comment: I have edited the question once check it

Answer (score 0):

Use angular ***$valid*** when the user will click the ***save*** button you could use $valid whether it has a value or empty in your controller like

```
    textBoxes.saveButtn = function(textFields) {
    if (textFields.$valid) {
                             <----Put your code ---->
            }
    else{} 
    }
```

Comment: its k..but when its not valid we should not save it right .then how to remove from the view

Comment: i have text boxes on popup which are created dynamically.So whenever i click on save button by entering somthing in it,the text is displayed as a lable and textbox is created beside it on parent form..Even when i does not enter anything in the text box the textbox is appending on the parent form without any label as we didn't enter anything in the text box.Now i need to validate it ,i mean whenever i didn't enter anything that must be not appended to the parent view.Hope you understood fyn

Comment: So the thing is please hide that save button until the user type or  right something inside the popup textbox ..

Comment: I have a number of text boxes right.I have written one and saved..agian i want to create the another ..So here i have saved without writing into it anything so how to validate at that time..

Comment: Every time are you saving the textbox individually right ? If s please disable the save button until the user write something in it .

Comment: Can i have an example.I am not getting understood

Comment: Use angular **ng-disabled**  like  `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success  
             ng-disabled="popForm.text.$dirty && popForm.text.$invalid">Save</button>`